# meaning and grammar in context

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> The non-Finnish degree granting eligibility to apply must be equivalent of 180 ECTS credits or more.

1. Is "The non-Finnish degree **granting** eligibility to apply"  the same as 
   "The non-Finnish degree **that/which grants** eligibility to apply"?
2. Does it mean that in order to apply, the degree must consist of 180 credits or more?

> The degree from a foreign university **must in the awarding country give eligibility for corresponding Master’s level studies**.

The structure of the bolded part of the sentence seems rather complicated to me, especially "give eligibility for".

I guess it means "the university giving you the degree have prepared you for your master's level studies(are able to study master level courses)"?   But I don't think that makes sense.

Comment: Are you sure the sentence says "equivalent OF"? It should be "equivalent TO."

Comment: 1 Yes 2 Yes. The second quoted passage means that your undergraduate degree is OK if you would be able to go on to do a Masters in the country where you got it without having to do more study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like "give/grant eligibility" is what is confusing you.

> **[eligibility](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/eligibility)** (n):  the fact of being allowed to do or receive something because you satisfy certain conditions:

A "grants eligibility" for B, if A *satisfies the conditions* for B.

"Granting eligibility to apply" is a participle phrase that modified the noun "degree".  It is the same grammar structure -- a [participle phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm) -- as something like:

> The tree **growing in the yard** is 100 years old.

"Tree" is the subject of "grow".  In the same way, "degree" is the subject of "grant (eligibility)".  The degree satisfies the conditions required to apply.

As for the rest, it's pretty straightforward grammar.  An expression of the form:

> A must be B

has little ambiguity.  B is a *required* condition of A.  So, yes, the (non-Finnish) degree is required to have the equivalent of 180 credits, and yes, the degree must (in the originating country) satisfy the conditions for the corresponding Masters-level studies.

In any case, all of this is just a fancy way to say that your degree must have been sufficiently *rigorous* to prepare you for graduate school, by satisfying certain conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but why wouldn't one say "The tree that grows in the year is 100 years old" ?

Comment: @jiannini  As with any language, there's usually more than one grammatical way to say something.  Both participle phrases and relative clauses can be used to modify a noun.  Sometimes one sounds better than the other, other times it's just a choice personal writing style.

Comment: Thank you so much again :)